# What's the best way to update a branch to the latest master while still keeping all the changes that were previously committed?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a git branch that is based off an old master. This branch has commits on it that the master does not have. I want to update the branch with the master's code, but keep the commits on the branch. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git fetch --all
git checkout your_branch
git merge someremote/master
```

Basically you first download all the updates for the remotes (without merging them), then you checkout to your branch and merge the updated master into your branch. If the master branch you are talking about is in the local repository and is updated, simple `git checkout your_branch; git merge master` will do the trick (will merge changes from master into your branch).

Comment: @chromedude, [rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) is another option.